Azure Logic App POST request to Microsoft Graph API succeeds manually but fails when invoked externally via webhook
I'm experiencing an issue with an Azure Logic App (Consumption) where a POST request to the Microsoft Graph API for appRoleAssignment works perfectly when I manually resubmit the failed action, but fails when the Logic App is triggered externally via a webhook.
Here are the details of my setup and the issue:
Logic App Configuration

HTTP Action Configuration:

{
  "method": "POST",
  "uri": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/servicePrincipals/{appObjectId}/appRoleAssignments",
  "headers": {
    "Authorization": "Bearer <access_token>",
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
  },
  "body": {
    "principalId": "user-or-service-principal-id",
    "resourceId": "resource-service-principal-id",
    "appRoleId": "app-role-id"
  },
  "retryPolicy": {
    "type": "fixed",
    "interval": "PT5S",
    "count": 3
  },
  "timeout": "PT30S"
}


Error Message
When the Logic App is triggered via a webhook, the request fails with the following error:
{
  "error": {
    "code": "Request_BadRequest",
    "message": "Not a valid reference update.",
    "innerError": {
      "date": "2024-07-18T14:21:29",
      "request-id": "ac44f253-5bbf-48bf-8c8e-c81603fd1320",
      "client-request-id": "ac44f253-5bbf-48bf-8c8e-c81603fd1320"
    }
  }
}


Payload and Headers

Request Payload:

{
  "principalId": "user-or-service-principal-id",
  "resourceId": "resource-service-principal-id",
  "appRoleId": "app-role-id"
}



Headers:

{
  "Authorization": "Bearer <access_token>",
  "Content-Type": "application/json"
}


Observations

The POST requestworks when I manually resubmit the action within the Logic App (from run history).
The same request fails when triggered externally via a webhook.
The access token, payload, URI, and headers are verified to be correct.
The error message suggests a BadRequest due to an invalid reference update.


What could be causing the POST request to fail when the Logic App is invoked externally via a webhook but succeed when manually resubmitted?
I have added logging actions in the Logic App to capture the state before and after the HTTP request. Here is the relevant part of my Logic App flow:
{
  "definition": {
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
    "actions": {
      "LogBefore": {
        "inputs": {
          "message": "Before HTTP Request: @string(body('WebhookTrigger'))"
        },
        "runAfter": {},
        "type": "Compose"
      },
      "HTTP": {
        "inputs": {
          "method": "POST",
          "uri": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/servicePrincipals/{appObjectId}/appRoleAssignments",
          "headers": {
            "Authorization": "Bearer <access_token>",
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
          },
          "body": {
            "principalId": "user-or-service-principal-id",
            "resourceId": "resource-service-principal-id",
            "appRoleId": "app-role-id"
          },
          "retryPolicy": {
            "type": "fixed",
            "interval": "PT5S",
            "count": 3
          },
          "timeout": "PT30S"
        },
        "runAfter": {
          "LogBefore": [
            "Succeeded"
          ]
        },
        "type": "Http"
      },
      "LogAfter": {
        "inputs": {
          "message": "After HTTP Request: @string(outputs('HTTP'))"
        },
        "runAfter": {
          "HTTP": [
            "Succeeded"
          ]
        },
        "type": "Compose"
      }
    },
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "outputs": {},
    "triggers": {
      "WebhookTrigger": {
        "inputs": {},
        "kind": "Http",
        "type": "Request"
      }
    }
  },
  "parameters": {}
}


Webhook Request Payload (captured in logs before the HTTP action)
{
  "principalId": "user-or-service-principal-id",
  "resourceId": "resource-service-principal-id",
  "appRoleId": "app-role-id"
}


Webhook Request Headers (captured in logs):
{
  "Authorization": "Bearer <access_token>",
  "Content-Type": "application/json"
}

Update (2024-07-18 18:00):
Upon further investigation, I found that -

IT FAILS: When I store the appRoleId (a GUID) in a variable and dynamically pass its value to the payload body, then the request fails.
IT WORKS: If I hard code the GUID for appRoleId in the body itself, then it works (I have copied and pasted the value from the variable).



My guess is that HTTP request to the Graph API is being fired before the Logic App has correctly evaluated the value of the variable.
Update (2024-07-18 18:25): Another interesting fact I forgot to mention is adding retries doesn't work here, because the error returned in 400. And even if I hard code the GUID of appRoleId in the payload body, it still fails unless I add a delay of at least 25 seconds and then retry the action further down after getting a 400 error. See the screenshot below.


And why does manually resubmitting the failed action work? Probably because in the previous "run," the Logic App has already evaluated the value of the variable.

Just check previous variables been inject step by step when failed. I think some variables not been correctly set in the previous run.

I have gone through the run history dozens of times, and I don't see any issues with variable initializing. Please check the last screenshot. After inserting a delay, the API calls succeed after failing the first time. The flow is using the same variables, and the values are the same. I think it is some kind of transient issue with Microsoft Graph API.

Can you show you logic app flow code with hiding secrets. I want to have a try at my side.

I have just tried at my side. both trigger with manual or POST request work well.

take caution here: If the role assignment already exist, the later assignment will failed with role existing.




My logicapp code flow:
{
    "definition": {
        "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
        "actions": {
            "HTTP": {
                "inputs": {
                    "body": {
                        "appRoleId": "@variables('appRoleId')",
                        "principalId": "@variables('spObjectId')",
                        "resourceId": "@variables('resourceId')"
                    },
                    "headers": {
                        "Authorization": "Bearer @{variables('bearerToken')}",
                        "Content-Type": "application/json"
                    },
                    "method": "POST",
                    "uri": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/servicePrincipals/@{variables('spObjectId')}/appRoleAssignments"
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "Initialize_variable_3": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "runtimeConfiguration": {
                    "contentTransfer": {
                        "transferMode": "Chunked"
                    }
                },
                "type": "Http"
            },
            "Initialize_variable": {
                "inputs": {
                    "variables": [
                        {
                            "name": "bearerToken",
                            "type": "string",
                            "value": "eyJ0eXAiOiJ**********************SaDEqPFePJIWA9tHaz34w"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "runAfter": {},
                "type": "InitializeVariable"
            },
            "Initialize_variable_1": {
                "inputs": {
                    "variables": [
                        {
                            "name": "resourceId",
                            "type": "string",
                            "value": "********************"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "Initialize_variable": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "InitializeVariable"
            },
            "Initialize_variable_2": {
                "inputs": {
                    "variables": [
                        {
                            "name": "spObjectId",
                            "type": "string",
                            "value": "**********************"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "Initialize_variable_1": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "InitializeVariable"
            },
            "Initialize_variable_3": {
                "inputs": {
                    "variables": [
                        {
                            "name": "appRoleId",
                            "type": "string",
                            "value": "************************"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "Initialize_variable_2": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "InitializeVariable"
            }
        },
        "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
        "outputs": {},
        "parameters": {
            "$connections": {
                "defaultValue": {},
                "type": "Object"
            }
        },
        "triggers": {
            "When_a_HTTP_request_is_received": {
                "kind": "Http",
                "type": "Request"
            }
        }
    },
    "parameters": {
        "$connections": {
            "value": {}
        }
    }
}

